# recognising "any date" in symbology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, date

Could anyone tell me how to select a date in the Symbology > Categories > Value field to express symbology for any cells that contain a date rather than having to add every date as a field to define my symbology?

I'm running this data from an excel sheet that gets continually updated so can not pick individual dates, I'd just like to know if there's a certain word or code for "any date" or "any value" that will trigger the symbology to work?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a symbol : *All other value* , just check this option when you active the button *Add all values* in your symbol list

Comment: Thanks, but I am using the "unique values, many fields" option and need the "all other values" to display other symbology. I have a date column in an excel sheet that has blanks and dates. The symbology picks up the <null> values. I just need to know what to put between the brackets for the symbology to pick up any date i.e. <??>